# Asking about how to play a piece of music from a tab On Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have difficulty in playing a part of the song from a guitar tab.Is it on topic to ask about it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean you can't find the fingering or you need help with the technique? Both of them would be on topic here.